# C# - Crawling XML RESTful webservice

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, rest

I need to get a lot of xml data from a webservice.

I send async requests using Task like this snippet

```
LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(10);
TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(lcts);
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
...
tasks.Add(factory.StartNew(() => GetRecords(country, names)));
...
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

The webservice has a lot of work to do in backend and so a lot of requests go in timeout or I receive a generic error from the webservice.

I am trying to solve this problem firstly tuning the number of LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler.

Some XML have a size of 2Mb, so I read the stream with XmlReader and I use `XmlNode node = new XmlDocument().ReadNode(reader);` for the data I need, but sometimes the program crashes or goes in deadloop (I suppose the cause is a not proper xml response by the webservice).

I think that creating an XDoc directly from the entire response is worse.

Could you suggest me a possibile reliable solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is it asmx or WCF web service?

Comment: A RESTful remote webservice, don't know the tecnology :)

Comment: So how do You want to increase it's performance? Because if you are receiving timeout errors from web service there is not much you can do with client about it. Except making your wait time longer.

Comment: Yes, I know that I have to wait longer, trying to don't load too much the webservice (using LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler or Thread.Sleep for example). Also my aim is to find a reliable solution on managing the retrieving of the data and the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If malformed XML is the source of the problem, you should only crawl the XML responses as strings and save/queue them locally for subsequent processing which you can improve over time as you see the kind of errors you are receiving when parsing the crawled XML.

In case of webservice timeouts, the task should just pause for a while and retry later.

**[EDIT:]**
For handling retries, you could use an exponentially increasing interval between retries (just like TCP/IP does it) - that way you will get fast reconnection in case the timeout was only very temporary and the server load will be eased down quickly in case it is seriously overloaded.

The sequence of intervals between retries can be e.g. 1 , 2, 4, 8 seconds,... up to 32 seconds or another empiric value which would be your maximum retry interval.

You should also maintain a backlog of entries which failed to download - timeout may not be the only reason.

Comment: Thank you Marek, I was just thinking about separating the crawling process and the response analyzing process and your solution is very good.

About pausing the Task now I am using something like `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);` and I resend the request; I should find a better solution.

You're right about the backlogging, I am just doing it, thank you ;)

Comment: You could use an increasing interval between retries - see the edit.